# getting images from firebase storage in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

In my Activity I use FireBase to download pics of my game from the storage.
If I run this code on my Activity it works but if I use it in my level class as a method, it just returns null.

This is my Activity:

```
pic = null;
answer = null;
option = null;
picture = null;
try {
    answer = File.createTempFile("buttonanswer", "png");
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://yougotit-8ce92.appspot.com");
    StorageReference levelDifficultRef = storageRef.child("easy");
    final StorageReference levelRef = levelDifficultRef.child(Game.LEVEL + 1);
    StorageReference levelAnswerRef = levelRef.child("pic" + "." + "jpg");

    levelAnswerRef.getFile(answer).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            answerV = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(answer.getPath());
            answerV.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    maingameLinarLayout.addView(answerV);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the level class this my code that doesn't work and returns null.

This is my level class:

```
public class Level {

    public static final String ANSWER="answer";
    public static final String OPTION="ops";
    public static final String PICTURE="pic";
    public static final String QUESTION="question";
    public static final String PNG = "png";
    public static final String JPG = "jpg";


    private File mainPicture,fadedPicture,opt1,opt2,opt3,answer,question;
    private int flag;//in easy level when reach to 6 it indicate that that level is ready //in medium and hard level when reach to 7
    private StorageReference storageRef;
    private String difficult;
    private Game game;



    public Level(Game game,FirebaseStorage storageIns,String difficult,int level) {
        flag = 0 ;
        this.game = game;
        this.difficult = difficult;
        this.storageRef = storageIns.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://yougotit-8ce92.appspot.com");
        StorageReference levelDifficultRef = storageRef.child(difficult);
        final StorageReference levelRef = levelDifficultRef.child(Game.LEVEL+level);

        if(difficult.equals(Game.LEVEL_HARD) ) {

        }
        if(difficult.equals(Game.LEVEL_MEDIUM) ) {

        }
        else {
            downloadPicture(levelRef, mainPicture, PICTURE, JPG);
            downloadPicture(levelRef, answer, ANSWER, PNG);
            downloadPicture(levelRef, opt1, OPTION + 1, PNG);
            downloadPicture(levelRef, opt2, OPTION + 2, PNG);
            downloadPicture(levelRef, opt3, OPTION + 3, PNG);
        }
    }

    private void downloadPicture(StorageReference levelRef,File f,String picName,String picFormat) {
        StorageReference pictureRef = levelRef.child(picName+"."+picFormat);
        f = null;
        try {
                f = File.createTempFile(picName,picFormat);
                pictureRef.getFile(f).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    flag++;
                    if(flag == 5) {
                        activeCallBack();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me figuring out what's going wrong?

Comment: What is returning null? The methods in your Level class are `void`. Do you have a logcat or debug prints?

Comment: sorry, I was not clear. this command : " " "pictureRef.getFile(f).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() "
doesn't return me the image from my firebase  when its in this Level class

Answer (score 0):

You are downloading different references in your Level class so this looks like an apples to orange comparison.

Try adding a addOnFailure in addition to addOnSuccess as I suspect that you are getting 404's for these other files.